# Input radio button is not calling functions as expected

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function call(a){
console.log("called by===>",a);
console.log("input one's checked value changed to ",document.getElementById('one').checked)
console.log("input two's checked value changed to",document.getElementById('two').checked)
}
```

```html
<input type='radio' id='one' name='one' value='x' onchange=call("one")>
<input type='radio' id='two' name='one' value='y' onchange=call("two")>
```

I have two radio buttons and both of them calls a method call when their value is changed.When I click on any radio button one's value will change to either true or false and other button's value changes to opposite value. So both input's value is changed but the input whose checked value is set to true alone are calling the function...

I expected that the function will be called twice once the button is clicked since checked value will be setted to true in one and false in other triggering onchange in both inputs 
Thanks in advance and please help me out.

Comment: what are you asking exactly?

Comment: It seems to be working fine, please clarify or reword the question so it is easy to understand what you are asking

Comment: this is doing exact job.

Comment: what is the expected behavior?

Comment: i expected that the function will be called twice once the button is clicked since checked value will be setted to true in one and false in other triggering onchange in both inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point in triggering `onchange` per input.

Radio buttons only allow one selection, so you should only care about the newly selected value.

If you do need to know about every input change you probably need `checkboxes` instead of `radio buttons`.